# Selenium error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am trying to open blank html template by selenium and I get error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
```

The blank page html is this. It should open, right? Same command opens https://www.youtube.com well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

what is wrong with this page?

Answer (score 0):

So I learned that when you want to open file in selenium the filename must have `file://` at the beginning. This is the correct format:

```
browser.get('file:///home/blanktest.html')
```